# Lisp regexp matching numbers with or without constant type identifiers ( 3.2 or 3.2f )

Tags: regex, emacs, numbers, lisp, font-lock

Question:
I'm looking to create a number font-lock face in emacs but I'm having trouble getting a regular expression that matches what I need. Here is what I have:

```
"\\<\\([0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*\\)+\\(d\\|f\\)?\\>"
```

What I want it to match:

1. 2
2. 2.1
3. 2.1f or 2.1d
4. .1f  or .1d

What I don't want it to match

1. 2.
2. 2.f or 2.d
3. f or d

Current problems:

Currently it works mostly but it doesn't match numbers like .2 or .2f because it doesn't pick up the (.) before the numbers. It also currently matches a single "f" or "d" anywhere in the code so variable names as f or d get matched. What am I missing here? I've fiddled with this every lunch break for the last week or so, I'm stumped.

Comment: I think you still need an extra backslash before the `\.` in your solution. `\.` within a string literal produces the single character `.`; for the backslash to work as a regexp escape character you need to double it: `\\.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex like this (PCRE syntax):

```
(\d*\.\d+|\d+)[fd]?
```

(Anchor it as required.)

Translated to Emacs style regex (by [Jon O](https://stackoverflow.com/users/725091/jon-o)):

```
"\\<\\([0-9]*\\.[0-9]+\\|[0-9]+\\)[df]?\\>"
```

Comment: That one wasn't working for me, though it reads like it would work perfectly. I ended up experimenting a bit and got crazy stuff like this that doesn't work:    

    `"\\\\(<[0-9]*\\(\\(\.[0-9]+\\)\\|[0-9]+\\)+\\)+\\(d\\|f\\)?\\>"`

and finally up with this:

    `"\\<\\([0-9]+\\|\.[0-9]+\\|[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\\)[fd]?\\>"`

which works almost perfectly except it picks up values like f3. It wouldn't pick up f or d by itself but f3 it picks up? These regular expressions are killing me.

Comment: The Emacs regexp in the answer still needs a doubled backslash before the first `|` in order to work. You could also write it like so: `"\\<\\([[:digit:]]*\\.[[:digit:]]+\\|[[:digit:]]+\\)[df]?\\>"`

Comment: @JonO thanks for the fix, Qtax's expression works perfectly now, and it's so much more simple than mine.